# WP8 : Setting Image width to device width in Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, html, css, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 application that uses the WebBrowser control. Within the control, I am loading an image and I want it to be exactly the width of the phone. I am having problems with that.

In code, I get the screen width and scale factor:

```
var initalWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
var factor = Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100.0;
var screenWidth = (initalWidth / factor).ToString();
```

I then pass screenWidth to my html that is loaded in the browser control which sets the width of my image.

This is the behavior that I see:

**Lumia 520**

```
initial width= 480
factor = 1
screenWidth = 480
```

Desired Result: Image is exactly the width of the phone.

**Lumia 920**

```
initial width= 480
factor = 1.6
screenWidth = 300
```

**Undesired Result: Image is about 80 pixels too small for the screen.**

I do not understand why it works on the 520 and not on the 920. Am I doing something wrong here?

In my HTML code I am using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and

```
 @-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you want. Because you are getting the right thing? If you want them to fill the same space in pixels, That is what is happening now. If you want them to fill the same relative space you should not use scalefactor`?

Comment: I would like my image to be exactly the width of the phone. My method above achieves that for the Lumia 520, but not for the Lumia 920. The resulting image width is smaller than the screen width.

Comment: Exactly because of the scale. What you are doing is making it the relative same size. I.e. filling a number of pixels. By not using the scale everything should be fine

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I see on the Lumia 920. The reported screen width is 480, the scaled width is 300, but none of these work. The image width must be set to about **380** to fill the screen width exactly. I do not understand how that number can be obtained. I got 380 by trial and error.

Comment: On my lumia 920 it is 480, and have been on three different devices I tested. It is a specific Microsoft unit, such that it will scale on all devices. If you then want to Make your UI fit a resolution the scale factor is used.